# Abstract algebra of integration theories.

Tags: abstract-algebra, integration

Simple group theory is a generalization of basic addition and multiplication of numbers.  In this vein, is there an abstract generalization of integration which does not make reference to the mechanics of the specific integration calculations (e.g. measure theory) but instead characterizes the essence of integration and allows it to be defined in other contexts?

Comment: Functional analysis?

Comment: I would have guessed measure theory is the analogue of group theory that you're looking for. It axiomatizes measures the way group theory axiomatizes associative binary operations. I look forward to interesting answers here though...

Comment: I was hoping for something that leveraged a set of fundamental axioms which "integration" must satisfy, such that using measure theory was just one way to achieve that structure.  If one can prove that any theory which satisfies these basic axioms always induces a standard measure theoretic structure, that would be cool.  But my understanding is that some valid computation, for instance in statistical mechanics, uses "integration" without inducing a well defined measure on a well defined space.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Daniell Integral?

Answer (score 3):

[Differential Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) is one algebraic theory of integration. It tries to explain which differential equations can be solved in elementary means like ordinary Galois theory explains which polynomial equations can be solved be elementary means (that is, by radicals). In particular, it differential Galois theory tries to explain which functions can be integrated in elementary terms.